# Adding exception for a file to default programs in windows

Tags: windows, file-association

Windows 10 has a default programs section in settings where we can associate a default program to open the file with its file extension. I have a situation where I want to open all the .py files with VSCode(IDE) except few which I want to associate with python.exe. But when I change the file association it changes for all .py files. Any nice way to handle this without changing extensions back and forth?

Comment: Probably not. Consider creating shortcuts for the exception files.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This is a workaround. The following method requires administrator permission to change registry values.

**Basis:** After installing Python (any version), `.py` file is automatically associated with `python.exe`. In the following method, that `python.exe` association with `.py` extension is preserved. Because anytime we/users execute `.py` file with `python.exe` and this default file association helps to do it without typing `python.exe` in commands. Also Python files can be visually distinguished with blue-yellow pythons :) So what to do? Just add a context menu (i.e. right click dialog box) for `.py` file only which shows "Edit with VSCode" option.

**Procedure:** First check if `.py` is actually associated with `python.exe` (optional). Run these command:

```bat
assoc .py
ftype Python.File
```

From the first command output, grab the `Python.File` file type and write a text file as following:

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Edit with VSCode\command]
@="E:\\VSCode\\Code.exe \"%1\""
```

Here `E:\VSCode\Code.exe` is the full path of VSCode executable. The path can be changed with Registry Editor.

[image: Python.File_in_RegEdit]

Open `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Edit with VScode\command` registry in Registry Editor. Edit the `(Default)` value with your own VSCode full path. So what does this registry value do? It adds a context menu for `Python.File` file type (e.g. for `.py` files) which execute `Code.exe C:\path\to\abc.py` command.